# Fourier series of Bessel potential monotone

Tags: fourier-series, monotone-functions, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Suppose that there is a Fourier series:
\begin{equation}
K(x) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} m \left( \frac{k\pi}{L} \right) \cos\left( \frac{k\pi x}{L} \right), \quad x \in (-L,L),
\end{equation}
where $m(\xi) = (1 + \xi^2)^{-s/2}$, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, is a Bessel potential of order $s > 1$, and $L \in (0,\infty)$.  I know that the sum is uniformly convergent.

How can I show that this series is strictly decreasing on $(0,L)$? Is there an explicit formula for $K'(x)$?

Can we say something about the regularity of $K$?  I think $K$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{s-\epsilon,1}(-L,L)$ for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.  That is, $K$ is Hölder continuous when $s \le 2$ and continuously differentiable when $s > 2$.

Thank you for any reference/help.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your tags in order they are meaningful and non-redundant.